# Discord.js 12.5.1 MessageEmbed not working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a bot to manage my everyday tasks as a fun project. but I am stuck here:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined
```

I can't seem to find an answer that fits what I need. Here is my code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('t!test')) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("This is a title")
    .setDescription("This is a description")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter("This is a footer")
    .setAuthor("This is the author's name")
    .addField("This is a field", "this is its description")
    .setImage("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/cC-YBJkH2GXnX7MHMASUM9Gle1S1im3rDJj2K54A28w/%3Fcid%3D73b8f7b19a5ccc575679c0a7fc4a673b753e4ce993f35223%26rid%3Dgiphy.mp4/https/media2.giphy.com/media/Q8bEDnj9hZd6vivXSZ/giphy.mp4")
    .setThumbnail("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/cC-YBJkH2GXnX7MHMASUM9Gle1S1im3rDJj2K54A28w/%3Fcid%3D73b8f7b19a5ccc575679c0a7fc4a673b753e4ce993f35223%26rid%3Dgiphy.mp4/https/media2.giphy.com/media/Q8bEDnj9hZd6vivXSZ/giphy.mp4")
    message.channel.send(embed)
    }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated as I have been stuck on this problem for the pas 3 hours.

EDIT: I fixed the error! Here is the code for anyone who is having this problem:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { MessageEmbed, Client } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('t!test')) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("This is a title")
    .setDescription("This is a description")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter("This is a footer")
    .setAuthor("This is the author's name")
    .addField("This is a field", "this is its description")
    .setImage("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/cC-YBJkH2GXnX7MHMASUM9Gle1S1im3rDJj2K54A28w/%3Fcid%3D73b8f7b19a5ccc575679c0a7fc4a673b753e4ce993f35223%26rid%3Dgiphy.mp4/https/media2.giphy.com/media/Q8bEDnj9hZd6vivXSZ/giphy.mp4")
    .setThumbnail("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/cC-YBJkH2GXnX7MHMASUM9Gle1S1im3rDJj2K54A28w/%3Fcid%3D73b8f7b19a5ccc575679c0a7fc4a673b753e4ce993f35223%26rid%3Dgiphy.mp4/https/media2.giphy.com/media/Q8bEDnj9hZd6vivXSZ/giphy.mp4")
    message.channel.send(embed)
    }
});

client.login(process.env.token)
```

(The embed is an example..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining Discord before `new Discord.MessageEmbed()`: `const Discord = require('discord.js');`

Comment: Hey, Discord is already defined! Any other idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This means the variable Discord is defined but the value is `undefined`. It would be easy to solve with the full code(except token).